# Inverse Regular Expression for Url Path matching

Tags: java, regex, pcre

I need to configure a url matching pattern with inverse criteria. Something like this.

```
/endpoint/300[0-9]+ -> These should not match and everything else should match.
```

I am trying the negative look back with `\/endpoint\/(?!^300)\d+`, but is not quite working. Can somebody explain what I am missing?

Comment: You've kind of given yourself the answer already. Test for the pattern that _shouldn't_ match and break on that, but just continue code flow if it doesn't? No need to get crazy with a regexp for the opposite case, test for what should not be let through, and simply don't do the work if that matches.

Comment: I need to configure this on a tool that uses a property and the tool itself doesn't support the negative condition.

Comment: then the question isn't "java", please tag it for the correct language/tool.

Answer (score 0):

Just negate all possible values:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String pattern = "/endpoint/(?:3|[^3].*|30|3[^0].*|300|30[^0].*|300[^0-9].*)";
    Stream.of(
        "/endpoint/asdf",
        "/endpoint/3008",
        "/endpoint/300b",
        "/endpoint/30",
        "/endpoint/3",
        "/endpoint/2999"
    ).forEach(it -> {
        System.out.println(it + " -> " + it.matches(pattern));
    });
}
```

Stdout:

```
/endpoint/asdf -> true
/endpoint/3008 -> false
/endpoint/300b -> true
/endpoint/30 -> true
/endpoint/3 -> true
/endpoint/2999 -> true
```

However if you need to negate `"/endpoint/"` part too - bad news, you will need to negate it the same way.